# Is Cartan's magic formula applicable to time dependent vector fields?

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms

Cartan's magic formula states:

$$\mathcal{L}_v\omega = i_v\mathrm{d}\omega + \mathrm{d}i_v\omega$$

Is this also true for time dependent vector fields? If so: How can I prove it? If not: Is there a simple counter-example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure what you mean. We can apply Cartan's formula on $M\times\mathbb R$, interpreting the vector field and $\omega$ as lifted.

Comment: How do you define the Lie derivative of a time-independent vector field?